# Permuting the rows of a matrix (and corresponding vector) using CUDA/Thrust

Tags: matrix, cuda, permutation, thrust

I would like to permute the rows of a matrix that is stored as an interleaved array (i.e. backed by a vector in row-major C-style format) and apply the same permutation to the elements of a corresponding vector.

Say the matrix dimensions are RxC and the corresponding vector has R elements.

My current idea is to generate a permutation of R indices and then use `thrust::stable_sort_by_key` to permute the vector as shown [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#sorting).

I can then create another permutation vector that repeats each element of the one I previously created C times.

So if R = 4, C = 3 and the original permutation index vector was [4, 2, 3, 1] the permutation vector for the matrix would be [4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1].
By using stable sort, the elements in a row of the matrix should not get permuted.

My question is then if there is a better/more efficient way to do this, using Thrust or plain CUDA.

Example:

Original matrix:

```
[ 1 1 1 1 ]
[ 2 2 2 2 ]
[ 3 3 3 3 ]
[ 4 4 4 4 ]
[ 5 5 5 5 ]
```

Original vector:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Permutation order:

```
[5 3 1 2 4]
```

Permuted matrix:

```
[ 5 5 5 5 ]
[ 3 3 3 3 ]
[ 1 1 1 1 ]
[ 2 2 2 2 ]
[ 4 4 4 4 ]
```

Permuted vector:

```
[5 3 1 2 4]
```

My use case is that I have a matrix of features and a vector of corresponding labels for each example. I would like to permute the matrix and apply the same permutation on the vector, as the shuffle step before an iteration of SGD.
The reason I want to have contiguous rows and iterate through them is that I plan to use cuBLAS gemv to perform the matrix-vector operations, which assumes that the matrix is laid out in a similar way in memory (albeit in column-major format which means I need to call it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165916/209882))

Comment: could you please add a small but **complete** example of what you want to achieve? what is the input matrix, what is your desired output? what do you want to do **after** permutation?

Comment: Since reads/writes to global memory are very expensive, if you're just moving data around then it's hard to get a benefit from CUDA.  If the matrix is very large (1000s of columns) you might eke out some improvement but it will not be very impressive.

Comment: If you are working in thrust, I would suggest not permuting or sorting the matrix at all.  Use a calculated lookup index to retrieve the correct element according to the desired row permutation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella my thinking (and shown in CPU implementations of SGD) was that since I have to iterate through the whole feature matrix, making sure that the data accesses are contiguous, instead of random , overcomes the cost induced from permuting the matrix before each iteration. The shuffling is necessary in order to ensure convergence.

Comment: Making sure data accesses are contiguous is a very good goal/target when coding for the GPU.  It promotes efficient use of the memory subsystem (coalesced access).  However the contiguous nature of each row, permuted or not, should be sufficient to meet this target for reasonably large-width matrices.  I'm not suggesting you shouldn't shuffle algorithmically -- of course that is necessary.  What I'm suggesting is to avoid the data movement associated with shuffling,   And you should be able to do so without sacrificing coalesced access.

Comment: @RobertCrovella in that respect I am limited since I would like to use cuBLAS gemv to perform the matrix vector operations needed, which means my data need to be contiguous in memory (as in rows of the matrix need to be contiguous, not just the elements in a row).

Comment: That makes sense.  That is why I prefaced my initial comment with "If you are working in thrust...".  You mentioned thrust in your question but made no mention of cublas (till now).  In that case, I would suggest simply using indexed copying -- sorting is overkill.  Your "permutation order" vector gives you everything you need to rearrange both the matrix and the vector without the need for sorting.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037886/matrix-columns-permutation-with-cublas) may give you some ideas as well.

Comment: Thanks for another great write-up @RobertCrvella! Sorry for not mentioning the cuBLAS requirement, this whole effort is about seeing if I an get better performance by using cuBLAS operations vs. using the Thrust-based implementation I have currently that accesses matrix rows at random order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is then if there is a better/more efficient way to do this, using Thrust

I believe there is.  The permutation vector gives you all the information you need to directly copy the contents of the input matrix to the permuted matrix, without the need for sorting.

A useful [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) feature for this is the `permutation_iterator`.   The permutation iterator allows us to re-order on-the-fly our selection of input elements to be used in any operation.  If we provide an appropriate index calculation functor, we can pass a linear index (via a `counting_iterator`) to the index functor, to create (via a `transform_iterator`) the appropriate permuted input index for any element in the copy operation.

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t1061.cu
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

typedef int mytype;

struct copy_idx_func : public thrust::unary_function<unsigned, unsigned>
{
  size_t c;
  unsigned *p;
  copy_idx_func(const size_t _c, unsigned *_p) : c(_c),p(_p) {};
  __host__ __device__
  unsigned operator()(unsigned idx){
    unsigned myrow = idx/c;
    unsigned newrow = p[myrow]-1;
    unsigned mycol = idx%c;
    return newrow*c+mycol;
  }
};


int main(){

  const mytype mat[]   = {1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5};
  const mytype vec[]   = {1,2,3,4,5};
  const unsigned per[] = {5,3,1,2,4};

  const size_t msize = sizeof(mat)/sizeof(mytype);
  const size_t vsize = sizeof(vec)/sizeof(mytype);
  const size_t psize = sizeof(per)/sizeof(unsigned);
  const size_t cols  = msize/vsize;
  // const size_t rows  = vsize;
  assert(msize%vsize == 0);
  assert(vsize == psize);

  thrust::device_vector<mytype>   d_m(mat, mat+msize);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype>   d_v(vec, vec+vsize);
  thrust::device_vector<unsigned> d_p(per, per+psize);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype>   d_rm(msize);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype>   d_rv(vsize);
  std::cout << "Initial Matrix:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(d_m.begin(), msize, std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, ","));

  // permute the matrix
  thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_m.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned>(0), copy_idx_func(cols,thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_p.data())))), msize, d_rm.begin());

  std::cout << std::endl << "Permuted Matrix:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(d_rm.begin(), msize, std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "Initial Vector:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(d_v.begin(), vsize, std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, ","));

  // permute the vector
  thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_v.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned>(0),  copy_idx_func(1,thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_p.data())))), vsize, d_rv.begin());

  std::cout << std::endl << "Permuted Vector:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(d_rv.begin(), vsize, std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

$ nvcc -o t1061 t1061.cu
$ ./t1061
Initial Matrix:
1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,
Permuted Matrix:
5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,
Initial Vector:
1,2,3,4,5,
Permuted Vector:
5,3,1,2,4,
$
```

Notes:

1. Permuting the vector operationally is identical to permuting the matrix.  We simply treat the vector as a matrix of one column.
2. As discussed in the comments, if the use-case were entirely within thrust, there might be no need to copy elements at all.  The `permutation_iterator` allows us to select elements from the original matrix in any permuted order, and we can simply pass this construct to any thrust operation that needed the original matrix in a permuted order.

Comment: Would using swap_ranges instead of copy_n work in this case? I understand this is premature optimization, but theoretically if my matrix was so big that a copy couldn't fit into the global memory, I could use that in order to swap rows in the matrix instead of copying them to a new one, correct?

Comment: I would think you should be able to make that work, if you replaced your permutation vector with a sequence of swaps.  It's likely to be slower than a single copy operation, I think.  By the way, if the matrix is so big that a copy couldn't fit into global memory, it's unlikely that your sort method would work either.  Sorting requires `O(n)` temporary storage, which thrust will attempt to allocate when you call `sort`